# Variable in matlab workspace that can be used from every function without passing it as an argument

Tags: matlab, variables

i am running an optimization in MATLAB with optimtool.

i have defined a function "Find(x)" that takes only the variable x as argument.

Inside my function i call another function that gives me a matrix of 3D points. I call this matrix p and its size is 200 x 3.

I want to avoid the same calculation of p every time since it doesn't change when the optimization tool runs the function.

How can i make the calculation of p once in my workspace and my function use this p without calculating it?

Thanks.

Comment: ok found it. this can be done inside my function as follows p_ = evalin('base','p');  It's supposed that p has been already calculated in the workspace 'base'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [PERSISTENT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/persistent.html) variable in your function. These are calculated only on the first use and persist until the next time the function is executed.

Comment: +1 But I don't think that's quite how it works. He'll have to use [isempty](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/isempty.html) to determine if this is the first use of the variable and assign it in that case.

Comment: It works. @Praetorian: do you mean i have to use "isempty" to avoid the calculation again?
without the use of "isempty" the variable is recalculated every time i call the function

Comment: @user452065 I believe so, you can try it by putting a breakpoint in the function that calculates the matrix and see if it is hit every time `Find(x)` is called.

Comment: @Praetorian - Yes, ISEMPTY is required to check if the variable has been initialized.

Comment: @user456065 - An alternative to persistent variables is to define `Find(x)` as a [nested function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-39683.html) so that both it and the containing function have access to `p`. This allows you to broaden the scope of `p` without resorting to global variables. The usefulness of this solution is of course dependent on the structure of your modules.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use assignin() to make the variable permanent in the workspace you are in. Check it out using MATLAB's help function. You can also save it as a .mat file in your home directory and have it load at the beginning of the function call.